# The title attribute contains line breaks if there is spoiler text or an image, and is inconsistent between the pages

Tags: bug, search, user-interface, accessibility

It seems that while the title attribute for each question link on the front page of each SE does not include the spoiler text or pictures, the line breaks still are still present in the source code. This seems to be present on both graduated and beta sites.

**This behavior is consistent on all of the filters on the front page:**

SciFi.SE (with spoilers):

[Q: What was the motivation behind the conspiracy in Star Trek VI?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/38306/what-was-the-motivation-behind-the-conspiracy-in-star-trek-vi)

[image: Spoilers on SciFi.SE]

Anime.SE (with image):

[Q: Have there been any anime with actual product placement?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/4257/have-there-been-any-anime-with-actual-product-placement)

[image: With image on Anime.SE]

**The Search pages doesn't have this problem, because the title attribute text is the title question:**

SciFi.SE:

[image: Search page from SciFi.SE]

Anime.SE:

[image: Search page from Anime.SE]

**On the Unanswered and Question pages, there does not seem to any title tags on the the questions using any of the filters on each page.**

This behavior seems to be a bit inconsistent when there are title attributes on the front and search pages. I not sure if this is intended or not, but it may be an accessibility issue (not describing where the link is going).